# Is there a way to remove an element of a string array?

Tags: python

What I'm trying to say is that I am trying to read off some file

```
v 0.0 0.0 0.0
v 1.0 0.0 0.0
v 0.0 1.0 0.0
f 2 1 3
```

and take them into an array that looks like this:

```
['0.0 0.0 0.0','1.0 0.0 0.0','0.0 1.0 0.0','2 1 3']
```

I've used readlines() and split() but I still can't figure out how.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Well, yeah. I'm currently working on the .obj to .vtk conversion in python code using Linked-list. And this question came out of it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to read in a .obj file. To that end, it seems like the prefix might matter. That aside, I think that

```
   lines = [l.split()[1:] for l in open(filename,'r').readlines()]
```

ought to work.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.

Comment: But I'm still wondering how I could bring the rest of the lines. This code only gives me the last line